# Android canvas sizing

Tags: android, canvas

When I creating custom View which is extends by android.view.View I used onDraw methods to draw something with canvas.

For example I created RectangleTextView and inside the onDraw methods I did like this

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,100,100,paint);
```

to create rectangle background with red color and it's might have 100 w/h (square)
and I draw next stuff to provide text with

```
canvas.drawText
```

and finally I got my own custom view and use it as xml
like

```
<com.my.RectangleView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But the thing is we set the exact point for **xy axis** so
layout_width="match_parent" won't effect to canvas's width, it's will always be 100 w/h as we set.

also what if I put a long string in canvas.drawText methods? the first rectangle shape's width that I drew will always be 100 and the text will draw outside of that according to string's length.

How can I set the canvas's w/h according to the xml attributes.

How can I wrap the first rectangle shape over string?

Comment: Is it only for painting?

Comment: Use onSizeChanged method and canvas size.

Comment: @gobucsg yessir

Comment: Only painting mean you can use background or tint something in the XML itself... Why you're going with custom class!?